# How can set javascript variable value as id attribute of a html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have the following JavaScript in a HTML page

```
 <html>
 <script>
 var i=0;
 function data()
      {
        i++;
        var id="form"+i;
       }

   </script>
  <body>
  <a href="#x" onclick="data();"</a>
  </body>
  </html>
```

How do I get the value of the variable id as the id if the  tag.please anyone help me

Comment: `onclick="data.call(this);"` then in data(): `this.id = id`

Comment: `this.id = id` will help you to assign id for the current element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
 <script>
 var i=0;
 function data(ele)
      {
        i++;
        ele.setAttribute("id","form"+i);
       }

   </script>
  <body>
  <a href="#x" onclick="data(this);"</a>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: but i need set id to another <a> tag in the same page

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to add id to element. Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anilnamde/92QJJ/) its using JQuery.

Though i really don't understand the reason you wanted to assign ID dynamically. If you wanted to read the elements that's why? then i would suggest there are [better ways to read elements](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) instead of generating dynamic id's. Check getElements by tag and class name.

```
<div class="IMDIV">
    Here is element
</div>

$(function(){
    $(".IMDIV").attr("id", "testId")
});
```