# How can I use javascript variable as html's div id?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
Var x="....";
<\script>
<div id = x> 
Some content 
<\div>
```

As u can see in the above code I want to use the variable x as div's id but its not working. 
Any suggestions plz...

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20282655/5835354

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the element’s `id` in your javascript code. See the code snippet below, the text apppears red because the javascript attaches the id `red`, stored in your variable `x`, to the `div`.

```js
var x = 'red';

document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].id = x;
```

```css
#red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Some content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not impossible.
If you want to add id to elements dynamically, you should wait until document will be loaded. Then run script like:

```
var el = document.querySelector() // with some selector rule
// and set  attribute 'id'
el.id = 'myId';
```

Perhaps you should tell what you want to do and find another way